# Why android application shows appbar twice?

Tags: android, android-studio

It shows app name and fragment toolbar even if I use `supportActionBar.hide` and `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`

[image]

Comment: please include all relevant code, otherwise the best we can do is guess

Answer (score 0):

Add this in style

```
<style name="Theme.ProjectName.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then add this in activity tag inside manifest

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjectName.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding PlaceholderFragment in your activity. -->

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.your_container, new 
PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

Now PlaceholderFragment class is inflating the same layout as your activity as -->

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
return rootView;
}
```